# Meteor DataTables Search() regexfor contains

Tags: regex, meteor, datatables

Regex is not my friend.  I'm looking to do what I believe to be a fairly simple search() on a datatable.  What I'm trying to do is return all rows whose column value == the current user. So... what I have is...

```
table.column( 3 ).search( '(\b' + Meteor.user().username + '\b)', true, false, true );
```

I've also tried this using DataTables smart search, but that didn't work either:

```
table.column( 3 ).search( Meteor.user().username, false, true, true );
```

In both cases DataTables returns 0 rows when I .draw.

I think what I need to do is get the right regex for contains and I'll be good to go!

Comment: what I would do first is to make sure that  Meteor.user().username is returning what you want with a console.print( Meteor.user().username) or something else that varifies that its a valid/correct string.

Comment: Actually, even easier - I would do this first .... table.column( 3 ).search("DBName", false, true, true ); .... And hard code the name to see if it returns any results. If it doesnt, then you know your syntax is off, if it does, then you know its something with .username

Comment: And to learn/practice your regex fu: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Good thoughts.  I'm seeing funky behavior.  Exact same string, but even if I use column sort "tomj" and "tomj" are not being sorted together.  Going into robomongo I can verify things are the same at the document level.  Im going to try playing around with using a hidden _id column.

Comment: more testing... turns out the issue I'm having is not w/ the Regex, but rather the DataTable is not reactive.  Such that when I add a new cell value the sort or search do not account for it until I've reloaded the page...  I'm going to explore:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736998/meteor-make-datatables-reactive...